# VB.NET - Implement Interface in LinqToSql

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

How do I go about implementing an interface for a LinqToSql class in VB.NET?

I've created the partial and added the explicit implementation, but Visual Studio is complaining that these properties already exist in the code created by the LinqToSql model. Error message is that the properties all have multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Option Strict and Option Explicit are on.

Code in my partial is as follows:

```
Partial Public Class YouthResidence
    Implements IAddress

    Public Property Street1 As String Implements IAddress.Street1
    Public Property Street2 As String Implements IAddress.Street2
    Public Property City As String Implements IAddress.City
    Public Property State As String Implements IAddress.State
    Public Property ZipCode As String Implements IAddress.ZipCode

End Class
```

Edit: I know I can wrap the model properties with a different name in the partial, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If your other partial class already has those properties, why not just keep the `Implements IAddress` but remove these properties you created entirely?

Comment: @Thraka - The other partial is generated by the LinqToSql model. I have very little control over that, just my own partial.

Comment: I know. What I'm saying is that the error sounds like the other partial has these fields declared, you're duplicating them. Remove them (from your partial) and see if it works. If your interface wants those properties to be declared, and the other partial provides them, then you've satisfied the interface contract. No need to declare the properties yourself.

Comment: I see the problem now

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with how VB.NET implements interfaces. It doesn't support implicit interfaces like C# does. So you always have to tie a specific member to the interface declaration. Annoying for partial classes. You can hide these though from consumers and make sure that they just talk to the original member

```
Private Property ZipCode_Hidden As String Implements IAddress.ZipCode
    Public Get
        Return ZipCode
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ZipCode = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Here I declared the property as private so that anyone using the class doesn't see ZipCode_Hidden and if you cast the object as the `IAddress` interface, it will automatically wrap the other partial class' member.

There is a suggestion on the Roslyn project to address this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3654